# In Angular 2+ what is the difference between using a router outlet and nested components

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components

I am working on an Angular 5 app on a team with a few other developers and I realized that the way I am setting up my components is different than the way some of the others on the team are doing it.  I don't know which way is better or even what the real difference between the two ways is.  Here is what I am doing:

In my app-routing.module.ts I have some routes set up like so:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'parent',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'child', component: ChildComponent }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then my parent template looks something like this:

```
<div>
  ... a bunch of html
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  ... more html
</div>
```

And the child looks like this:

```
<div>
  ... irrelevant html
</div>
```

While this method works for me for my particular use case, it's important to note that in my use case the child element is not getting a bunch of data from the parent.  In my setup anything that needs to be communicated from parent to child is done via a shared service.

In contrast, this is how a colleague of mine has it set up for his similar structure:

Note, I'm not going to show you his route because there is only one route, no parent/child relationship.  Here is the parent html:

```
<div>
  ...some html
  <app-child [child_referenceable_data_object]="parent_data_object"></app-child>
  ...more html
</div>
```

now here is the child:

```
<div>
  ...html
  <div [ngClass]="child_referenceable_data_object.class">whatever</div>
  ...more html
</div>
```

This works for him because he has to pass a lot of data into the child.  Obviously both of these approaches have their advantages/disadvantages, but what are they exactly?

Edit.  I just realized i'm not really getting to the point of my problem so I'm going to illustrate it here.  What I have shown above is how the system is currently setup.  In my colleagues code, the parent is a list of things and the child is a detail view of one of those things.  The child only shows up when you click on one of the elements in the list.

I now have a need to open my colleagues page with one of the children already open.  Because of this, it seems i need to modify his code to use a nested route as I have used in my code, however because of the way he is passing data from parent to child this is difficult.

He is currently using a service to get a list of all the data for the parent list and then passing one element of that data to the child.  I'm thinking that some sort of service is my solution as well but not sure.

Comment: You would use routes to use different components

Comment: You would use routes to use different components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use router-outlet if your page has dynamic content.

Imagine you have a layout component, which has a toolbar, sidebar and the content, pretty much like any admin dashboard. In that case, router-outlet is the way to go, because the page will remain the same and the changing part is the content.

The parent > child way should be used if the two are directly related, for example a product list > product detail relationship.

Note that both ways are similar and, if you're not getting info through the service, that means something is wrong with your service or the way your data is been handled and passed.

Comment: So in my colleagues case the parent and the child are directly related.  the parent has a list of things and the child is the detail of one of those things.  The problem i'm facing is that now I want to go directly to a view where a particular child is already open so it seems that i need a specific route for this so i'm inclined to change his code to match my parent/child route setup, however they are in fact directly related which from what you are saying here would be a good reason to use the component nested in component method.

Comment: This is actually the way I've built my apps, but maybe, a refactoring is needed. What would be ideal is to talk to your colleagues and define a standard to follow, whether it's using routes or not.